# Adding a class via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some code dynamically created by Sigma, which looks like this:

```
<div id="myGrid1_headDiv" class="gt-head-div">
<div class="gt-head-wrap">
<table id="myGrid1_headTable" class="gt-head-table">
<tbody>
<tr class="gt-hd-row">
<td class="gt-col-mygrid1-uid">
<div class="gt-inner gt-inner-left" unselectable="on" title="#">
<span>#</span>
<div class="gt-hd-tool"><span class="gt-hd-icon"></span>
<span class="gt-hd-button"></span>
<span class="gt-hd-split" style="cursor: col-resize; "></span></div></div></td>
<td class="gt-col-mygrid1-p_deldate">
<div class="gt-inner gt-inner-left" unselectable="on" title="Planned Delivery Date">
<span>Planned Delivery Date</span>
<div class="gt-hd-tool"><span class="gt-hd-icon"></span>
<span class="gt-hd-button"></span>
<span class="gt-hd-split" style="cursor: col-resize; "></span></div></div></td>
```

I am trying to target the un-classed spans( # and Planned Delivery Date), in order to style them, with:

```
  $("div.gt-inner:first-child span")
    {
          $(this).addClass("celltitle");
        };
```

but it has no effect. As you can see, there other spans around it that I don't want to touch. What am I doing wrong?

=====
Final Answer for others using Sigma Grid:

Thanks to @minitech for the pointers, the answer is to add to Sigma Grid's gridOption with:

```
onComplete:function(grid){ 
 $('div.gt-inner > span').addClass('celltitle'); //add cell title after grid load
}
```

Comment: And what error does that JS code give you (because it's not valid syntax)?

Comment: PS: the jquery is in the  $(document).ready(function().

Comment: The proper format would be: `$("div.gt-inner:first-child span").addClass("celltitle");`

Comment: @Jasper: Actually, it is! You can "thank" JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion for that.

Comment: Full doc ready stuff: 
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var currentWeek = <?php echo $weekno; ?>; // Important: sets the current week number for subsequent JS files
         $('.spin-button').spinit({min:1,max:53,stepInc:1,pageInc:20, height: 22, initValue: currentWeek });
          $("div.gt-inner:first-child span")
        {
              $(this).addClass("celltitle");
            };
           
     });

Comment: @minitech Yeah i posted it into JSfiddle and walaa, no errors, got me by suprise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've inserted an arbitrary code block in there. You need to use jQuery's `.each` function and pass your function; jQuery is a library, not a language construct.

```
$("div.gt-inner:first-child span").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("celltitle");
});
```

Or, more concisely, since `addClass` (like many jQuery functions) implicitly operates on the entire collection:

```
$('div.gt-inner:first-child span').addClass('celltitle');
```

Comment: Since you are doing the same thing to all possible elements in the selection, there is no need for the `.each()` loop.

Comment: @Jasper: Yup, I had just added that right before you commented :)

Comment: Thanks, but still not working, and now I know why... document ready is not truly ready, as I inserted a alert("boo!"); after that code. When boo appears, the titles, etc have not loaded as they are of the Sigma JS, and obviously take a bit of time. Maybe I need to add a delay or something?

Comment: @Onyx: Sigma JS probably has some kind of callback; you should handle that. Try the documentation, because I have no idea what Sigma JS is.

Comment: @minitech : thanks, I will check in the APIdocs; it is actually Sigma Grid; a JS based engine for creating a dynamic grid...nice, but a bit inflexible in places!

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

```
$("div.gt-inner:first-child span").addClass("celltitle");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g34SW/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
$("div.gt-inner span").addClass("celltitle")
```

Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ for more info.